# Is it possible to protect a directory from being deleted without it making read-only?

Tags: permissions, rm

There are some directories that I want to have edit access to, but I don't want to accidentally `rm` it. I have accidentally ran `rm -rf *` in the wrong directories before and want to safe proof against that.

I know I can make it read-only, but I still need to be able to edit it, just not remove entire directories easily.

Comment: To prevent deletion of the directory, you need to `chmod a-w <parent_directory>`.

Comment: please specify the unix-like you are running. (straightforward solution under OpenSolaris & derivatives)

Comment: @MC68020 I am using CentOS Linux 7

Comment: @treuss hmm why is it the parent directory and not the child directory if the child directory is what I want to prevent from being deleted? there are other directories within parent directory that I may want to delete

Comment: The directory is an "entry" in its parent directory. Thus deleting the "child" is a modification to the "parent". Of course, as soon as there is something inside the "child" directory, the permissions of the "child"-directory also matter.

Comment: Ha too bad (not being under OpenSolaris regarding that purpose.) Then… what about renaming all what you care about with names starting with . (period) ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution would be to set the sticky bit and make sure the folder is owned by some other user (root probably being a good choice), but editable by your user.

https://www.cbtnuggets.com/blog/technology/system-admin/linux-file-permissions-understanding-setuid-setgid-and-the-sticky-bit

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *file attribute*s (flag) of the files you want to protect from `rm` (deletion).  Take a file named `testfile`; perhaps you want to copy one of your actual files to create `testfile` to experiment with; e.g.

```
$ cp realfile testfile 
$ ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 14 Oct 17 07:10 testfile
$
```

Set the ***append attribute*** on `testfile`. This mode allows you to add (append) data to `testfile`(but not delete (`rm`) it, and not change any existing data in the file):

```
$ sudo chattr =a testfile 
$ ls -l testfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 14 Oct 17 07:10 testfile 

#   note testfile permissions unchanged
#   try to delete (rm)...

$ rm testfile
rm: cannot remove 'testfile': Operation not permitted 
$ sudo rm testfile 
rm: cannot remove 'testfile': Operation not permitted
```

If you open `testfile` in an editor, you will find that you can make changes to it (additions, deletions), but it cannot be saved under the `testfile` file name.  However, we can put our editor in ***append mode***, make whatever additions we want and then save it under the `testfile` name.

Using the `nano` editor as an example, open `testfile` and add a couple of lines of text:

- Use `ctrl-X` to initiate an exit, then "Y" to confirm that the file should be saved.
- when the `File Name to Write: testfile` prompt appears, enter the `M_a` option from the keyboard (this is likely `ctrl-a`, or `esc-a`, depending on your keyboard, but see man nano for definitive guidance).
- When you've entered the correct keyboard sequence, the prompt changes FROM: `File Name to Write: testfile` TO: `File Name to Append to: testfile`. Hitting the `enter` key should complete the append operation successfully.
- confirm the successful append w/ `cat testfile` - or whatever
- to ***remove the append attribute***

```
$ sudo chattr -a testfile 
$ rm testfile
$
# testfile is deleted as its immunity is gone :) 
#
# of course the file can also be "fully edited" upon removal of the append attribute;
# just make your edits & then restore the append attribute, or use the -i attribute
```

See `man chattr` for options and details.